# RichFaces demo dataTableScrollerBean.java location

Tags: richfaces

I've noticed from [here](http://anonsvn.jboss.org/repos/richfaces/tags/3.3.2.SR1/samples/richfaces-demo/src/main/java/org/richfaces/demo/dataTableScroller/) that the contents is only the header

Revision 16532: /tags/3.3.2.SR1/samples/richfaces-demo/src/main/java/org/richfaces/demo/dataTableScroller

and no listing of the `dataTableScrollerBean.java` file which the `Edit Table/Modal Panel` demo JSF code refers to.  Where can I access it?  I'd like to try the demo out on my machine. I've posted to RichFaces but SO tends to respond faster.

Thanks

Mark

**EDIT**

I've found some code [(here)](http://seamframework.org/Community/AnySeamExampleUsingRichFaceBindingAttribute) on a forum fortunately which is as close as I've come so far.  Looks like it was written by one of the RichFaces authors, but when I included it, Eclipse is complaining about the Facet object which together with another forum and these

```
import javax.ejb.Stateful;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
```

suggest I may be missing j2ee.jar.  But I'm running this out of Tomcat which is not an ejb container.  I didn't think this RichFaces component required JBoss or equivalent so I must be doing something wrong.  All I'm trying to do is try out an Edit Table!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@BalusC, it's just me, Eclipse and a Tomcat 6 plugin.  But I like it like that - the more I have to do for myself the quicker I'll learn.  I've got 27.2k rep to get yet..  A helpful response though.  Strictly speaking the answer to the question is: [here](http://anonsvn.jboss.org/repos/richfaces/branches/community/3.3.X/samples/richfaces-demo/src/main/java/org/richfaces/datatablescroller/).

Answer (score 2):

Remove them, it's just cruft which is not required to get the code to work. You just have another way to manage the entities (JDBC, Hibernate, JPA, whatever), do you?